# Extend a jquery datepicker with custom properties

Tags: jquery

I want to extend my jquery `datepicker` with some other properties, so I used `$.extend` and my datepicker+myobj getting everything working as I need. Follows my code:

```
var meter_reading = 
{
  value : -1,
  valid : false,
  bullet : {},
  update_reading : function() {
    if (this.value > -1) {
        this.bullet.src = "./applications/" + app_id + "/green_bullet.png";
        this.valid = true;
      }  
      else {
        this.bullet.src = "/applications/" + app_id + "/red_bullet.png";
        this.valid = false;
      }
  }
}

var dps01 = $("#dp_Start01");
$.extend(dps01, meter_reading);
```

My problem comes when I create another customized datepicker :

```
var dps02 = $("#dp_Start02");
$.extend(dps02, meter_reading);
```

It seems dps02 gets the reference of the previous `myobj` (on `dps01`) and if adjust my custom properties of dps02 I'll adjust the dps01 instead.

I tried `new meter_reading()` and `new meter_reading` in extend function but it doesn't works.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I copied and pasted some code without making all adjustments.